# Wordpress: Facebook icon for comments overlaps the default icon

Tags: wordpress, facebook-comments

This is the default layout of the theme I'm using. There is a bubble denoting the number of comments for this post.
http://twitpic.com/b3hr1j/full

After I've installed the Facebook plugin and enabled the comments box, a facebook icon overlapped the default icon.
http://twitpic.com/b3hrxj/full

How could I remove one of them, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use in your `style.css`

```
.entry-header .comments-link {display: none;}
```

it'll hide the callout, but [here](http://randyzwitch.com/comment-bubble-twenty-eleven/) is a more detailed/better solution to hide the callout, also [this one](http://www.techtipsworld.com/remove-comment-bubble-posted-on-date-posted-in-category-and-tag-from-twenty-eleven-theme/207/) may help.

Comment: Perfect. And the two links are very useful. Thanks very much :)